# To hide the 2nd level of categories in high chart from xAxis?

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports

I made a column chart with 2 level (categories) but now i want to hide the second category from showing on xAxis. Is it possible to do that...this is highcart in jasperstudio. See the picture below highlighted in brown thats the one i want to hide

[image]

Comment: Could you post live example of your chart or the code you are using? Have you seen Axis.labels.step parameter? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step

Comment: i tried your suggsetion its not working the step merely skipped the label but some still there

Comment: could you post live example of your issue?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński sorry i dont quite understand what do you meant by live example kindly advise

Comment: By live example I mean for example jsFiddle showing your chart. Could you make an example with fixed data showing your chart? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński i don't believe if there is anything jsfiddle for jasperstudio...although the software using highcharts but the setting (properties) is slightly done differently

Comment: I hoped you are able to replicate the issue using standard highcharts code. Right now you post only an image showing your issue, could you post your code as well?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `labels: {enabled:false}` on the x-axis?